# mongodump fails error writing data for collection `XYZ` to disk

Tags: mongodb

when I am running mongodump script it fails error writing data for collection `XYZ` to disk

```
Failed: error writing data for collection `XYZ` to disk: error reading collection: read tcp x.x.x.x:44914->y.y.y.y:27017: read: connection reset by peer
```

at the same time, I see the log on mongo

```
I NETWORK  [conn5286] Error sending response to client: HostUnreachable: Connection reset by peer. Ending connection from X.X.X.X:44926 (connection id: 5286)
```

it's my script

```
rm -f /backup/data/*.gz

mongodump --host=mongo --db=trainer_bot --out=/backup/data/ --gzip --username=HHH --password=***
mongodump --host=mongo --db=trainer_image --out=/backup/data/ --gzip --username=GGG--password=***
mongodump --host=mongo --db=trainer_book --out=/backup/data/ --gzip --username=EEE --password=***
mongodump --host=mongo --db=trainer_expo --out=/backup/data/ --gzip --username=JJJ --password=***
mongodump --host=mongo --db=trainer_placement --out=/backup/data/ --gzip --username=CCC-password=***
```

HELP PLS

Comment: Same situation here. Not able to run mongodump for large collections (> 10G). Any news on that?

Comment: Did you find something? Having same totally random problem on small-medium collections